# Open source SharePoint alternative compatible with Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: sharepoint, open-source, dynamics-crm-2011

I saw that in MCRM, you have a "Documents" entity but you need a SharePoint location.

Should it be Microsoft SharePoint anyway or their is something to be able to use this entity or an other way to use functionality provided by SharePoint locations without buying SharePoint licenses like an open source solution compatible with Microsoft products.

Thanks!

Comment: No, you need a SharePoint location behind it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Sharepoint foundation that is free. We have implemented our CRM SharePoint integration that way.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/aa905690.aspx